# Problema en código html con nodemcu en arduino ide ajustar tamaño del botón

Tags: html, c++, arduino, esp8266

estoy programando en el arduino ide un codigo para un esp8266 con un servidor html en una ip local y necesito aumentar el tamaño de los botones. Adjunto el codigo y necesito ayuda. Gracias.
Voy a adjuntar el codigo como imagen ya que me da error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tienes una consulta de HTML, que es independiente de c++, Arduino o Esp8266. En todo caso, publica el código como texto; las imagenes no sirven para trabajar.

Comment: no puedo subirlo como texto, la web no me permite